# My TimeBased autoSendMail Trigger is not generated by my appScript when the trigger function is called by the button

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

the following error I got
"Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property create on object ScriptApp.ClockTriggerBuilder. [line: 13,]"

this is the code:

```
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(5)
  .create(); 
}
```

Comment: Hello,  Can you include more of your code since this seems like its only a small snippet of your code?

Comment: `function generateTimeBasedTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(5)
  .create(); 
}`  ....... **this is the function that is called in a button to generate trigger in appscript everytime it shows error while creating trigger object using create() property**

Comment: How are you receiving this error? Is this through the menu option "Run" -> "Test as add-on.." or "Run"->"Run function" or some other way. Additionally, is this run time V8 or V7?

Comment: @dev really need to show more code. does the function "myFunction" exist?

Comment: now a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61209467/my-timebased-autosendmail-trigger-is-not-generated-by-my-appscript-when-the-trig